# Tikz Overlay with details

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to detail my plots using TikZ overlay. My current code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{commath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*} \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[      
        every node/.style={anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt},
        x=9.5mm, y=5.1mm,
      ]   
     \node (fig1) at (0,0)
       {\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{Plots/untitled.36.png}};
       \draw[line width=0.5mm, blue]        (-82mm, 45mm) -- (-15mm, 45mm);
     \node (fig2) at (5,5)
       {\includegraphics[scale=0.085]{Plots/untitled.35.png}};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Using Tikz Overlay}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

This provides me the following figure:
[image]

**However, I'd like to detail my figure as follow**:

[image]

Please note that, I also want to have a ***dotted or dashed-dotted*** line (horizontal line on the left figure) as the cross section line.

The 2 image files I'm using are attached.
[image]

[image]

I appreciate your help.

Comment: related / duplicate: [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/123129)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, your picture is simple enough to be drawn directly with Ti*k*Z. Then you can avoid the fine tuning to adjust positions, scales, matching colors,...

For example, with this code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

% colors
\definecolor{my green}  {HTML}{255B37}
\definecolor{my gray}   {HTML}{4D4D4D}
\definecolor{my magenta}{HTML}{CF23E9}
\definecolor{my cyan}   {HTML}{24B2A2}

% styles
\tikzset{my node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=0mm,minimum size=4mm}}

\begin{document}\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.2mm,scale=1.5]
% left figure
\fill[my green] (-2.05,-1.33) rectangle (2.05,-0.97);
\fill           (-2.05,-0.97) arc (180:0:2.05cm and 0.23cm);
\fill[white]    (-2.05,-0.97) to[out=0  ,in=270,looseness=1.2] (-0.98,-0.12) --
                 (0.98,-0.12) to[out=270,in=180,looseness=1.2]  (2.05,-0.97);
\fill[my gray]  (-0.98,-0.12) rectangle (0.98,1.34);
\fill[my cyan]  (-0.28,-0.12) rectangle (0.28,1.34);
\foreach\i in{-1,1}
{
  \begin{scope}[x=\i cm]
    \draw (-2.04,-0.96) to[out=90-90*\i,in=270,looseness=1.2] (-0.97,-0.12);
    \fill[my magenta] (-0.93,1.34)  -- (-0.93,-0.12) -- (-0.8,-0.5) --
                      (-0.67,-0.12) -- (-0.67,1.34)  -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
}
% right figure (cross section)
\begin{scope}[shift={(4,0.61)}]
  \fill[my gray] (0,0) circle (0.98);
  \fill[my cyan] (0,0) circle (0.28);
  \foreach[count=\j]\i in{0,30,...,330}
    \fill[my magenta] (\i:0.8) circle (0.13) node [inner sep=0](C\j) {};
\end{scope}
% labels
\draw[blue,dotted] (-2.1,0.61) node [black,above] {cross} node [black,below] {section} -- (2.1,0.61);
\node at (4,2) {cross section};
\node[my node] (a) at (1.85, 2)    {\strut a};
\node[my node] (b) at (1.85, 0.15) {\strut b};
\node[my node] (c) at (1.85,-0.5)  {\strut c};
\node[my node] (d) at (1.85,-1.15) {\strut d};
\draw (-0.8,1.2)   -- (a) -- (0.8,1.2);
\draw (C4)         -- (a) -- (C7);
\draw (0,0.4)      -- (b) -- (4,0.61);
\draw (-0.8,-0.25) -- (c) -- (0.8,-0.25);
\node (L) at (3.1,-0.9) {\bfseries labels:};
\draw (L.south west) -- (L.south east);
\foreach[count=\ii]\i/\j in {a/label 1,b/label 2,c/label 3,d/label 4}
{
  \node[my node] (\ii1) at (2.9,-0.9-0.4*\ii)    {\strut\i};
  \node          (\ii2) at ([xshift=0.65cm]\ii1) {\strut-- \j};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

you'll get:
[image]

However, if you want to use your pictures, the solution is almost the same (plus the fine tuning, of course). You can do the following:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

% styles
\tikzset{my node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=0mm,minimum size=4mm}}

\begin{document}\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.2mm,scale=1.5]
\node               {\includegraphics[width=7.5cm]{left.jpg}};  % <-- change this for your picture
\node at (4.05,0.6) {\includegraphics[width=5.2cm]{right.jpg}}; % <-- change this for your picture
\node (C4) at (4.1,1.4)  {};
\node (C7) at (3.3,0.55) {};
% labels
\draw[blue,dotted] (-2.1,0.61) node [black,above] {cross} node [black,below] {section} -- (2.1,0.61);
\node at (4,2) {cross section};
\node[my node] (a) at (1.85, 2)    {\strut a};
\node[my node] (b) at (1.85, 0.15) {\strut b};
\node[my node] (c) at (1.85,-0.5)  {\strut c};
\node[my node] (d) at (1.85,-1.15) {\strut d};
\draw (-0.8,1.2)   -- (a) -- (0.8,1.2);
\draw (C4)         -- (a) -- (C7);
\draw (0,0.4)      -- (b) -- (4,0.61);
\draw (-0.8,-0.25) -- (c) -- (0.8,-0.25);
\node (L) at (3.1,-0.9) {\bfseries labels:};
\draw (L.south west) -- (L.south east);
\foreach[count=\ii]\i/\j in {a/label 1,b/label 2,c/label 3,d/label 4}
{
  \node[my node] (\ii1) at (2.9,-0.9-0.4*\ii)    {\strut\i};
  \node          (\ii2) at ([xshift=0.65cm]\ii1) {\strut-- \j};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and with this you'll get:
[image]

Comment: This is great! Thanks, Juan. Appreciate your time.